# Some Rhythmbox Shortcuts Stopped Working

Tags: shortcut-keys

In Rhythmbox on Ubuntu 21.10, some keyboard shortcuts still work (`ctrl` + `p` to play/pause, `ctrl` + `j` to select current playing track).

But some keyboard shortcuts stopped working:

- next track: `ctrl` + `→`
- previous track: `ctrl` + `←`
- play shuffle: `ctrl` + `u`
- play repeat: `ctrl` + `r`

How can you re-enable these shortcuts?

Comment: Did you do a recent update? Sometimes updates change things that you might want to fix.